# Running A Project Created in Xcode 8 on Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, debugging

Whenever I run my project that was created in xcode 8.3 on the new beta release xcode 9, I get this error:

> Failed to change owner of
>   file:///Users/aaronzheng/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96629718-46B0-4775-8A31-49857EE620B8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.CnVa3s/Study%20Club.app:
>   Error Domain=MIInstallerErrorDomain Code=4 "Failed to remove ACL"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f8c5d606530 {Error
>   Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=13 "Permission denied"
>   UserInfo={SourceFileLine=392, NSLocalizedDescription=open of
>   /Users/aaronzheng/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/96629718-46B0-4775-8A31-49857EE620B8/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.CnVa3s/Study
>   Club.app/GoogleMaps.bundle/bubble_left.png failed: Permission denied,
>   FunctionName=-[MIFileManager _removeACLAtPath:isDir:error:]}},
>   FunctionName=-[MIFileManager _removeACLAtPath:isDir:error:],
>   SourceFileLine=392, NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to remove ACL}

Nothing was wrong with the current swift syntax, I converted to the current swift syntax and changed the property on the build settings to swift 4.

Comment: That's not a Swift syntax error, so it's not surprising that syntax changes had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite not sure, but I think after /Devices is the Application Owner Id, so its the same for all apps that you build. I think that the switch to a new version of xcode might have changed said id. You might be able to reconfigure it in the info.plist file, but I think your best bet is rebuilding the storyboard and copying and pasting your source code into the new files. But without being able to see your code there isn't too much help you can actually get